# Practical rugged method for elevating water 7 feet high?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, hydraulics

At a very low-tech, rustic forest camp, I've built a 'water tower' connected to a [gravity-fed water filter](https://international.sawyer.com/products/sawyer-pointone-filter-bucket-adapter-kit-1-ft-hose/) to provide something like a clean water faucet. It's basically a 5 gallon bucket on top of a ~6' high platform, with a 1' long hose running down from it connected to a filter. It is idle for long periods of time and then used for a period of 1 to 9 days, receiving apx. 3 gallons of moderately turbid, acidic water input each day.

I want the end of the filter (i.e. the clean water spout) to be about waist high (way easier to work with than a spout only a couple inches above the ground). To accomplish this I could either shorten the filter's hose or raise the bucket, and thinking that height/gravity was important for a gravity fed filter, I opted to raise the bucket. This presented two challenges: I need a taller platform, and I need a way to fill the bucket when it's at or above head height. The taller platform was easy enough to build, but a sturdy enough ladder to carry water up to the bucket is harder to craft. How can I get water from ground level up in to a bucket that's rim is about 7' high?

The conditions on site are very rustic and remote. It's a long drive to get there, then a bit of a walk to camp (lugging gear in a backpack and by hand), and currently the only dry storage is makeshift via tarps (not reliably dry). I don't always go there with a large vehicle, so transporting a ladder back and forth isn't a great option, and if I leave a steel ladder there it will be exposed to extreme temperature swings & moisture. I'm envisioning some relatively primitive technology like a pulley, an Archimedes screw, or more compact easier-to-transport modern technology like a small hand-pump with a hose, but I know very little about the details of those options. So I ask Engineering.SE: what practical rugged method can I use to elevate water 7 feet high? If some kind of pump, what specs to look for and what other equipment will I need to make it work?

Bonus if the method can be scaled or setup in series so to move water further distances. As of now, to get water to the ground next to the water tower, one has to carry water by bucket up a steep ~100' slope that has ~75% grade.

Comment: Do a search on a hydraulic ram or ram pump...

Comment: I would keep it really simple in this situation with a hand powered pump. Lots of options should come up searching for "hand water pump".

Comment: Can a hand pump be used at the 'bottom' of the setup? Most hand pumps are for pulling water up from a well and pouring it out where it's being pumped, but I would want to pump closer to ground level where the water starts and would have a hose run from the pump outlet up to the water tower bucket.

Comment: For example @ericksonla could this pump move water upwards overhead? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siphon-King-36-in-Utility-Hand-Pump-with-72-in-Hose-48072/205346979

Comment: Review say so? I found the product data sheet and it doesn't mention a head or discharge pressure, so its hard to know. Well engineered piston/plunger pumps (like that style) can reach discharge pressure of 200 bar/3000 psi/really high in the air. So it is just a question of engineering/mfg quality.

Comment: Do you need to bring water up about 75’ from the source to your campsite?

Comment: @GisMofx that would be nice but is not the question here. We lug a bucket of water up from the river. Once it's up at camp, this question is how to perch it on a high platform/get it up in a water tower.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad.  As earlier comments have suggested, there are a number of potential solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Winch the bucket down, fill the bucket, then winch the bucket up. You're not trying to move this some huge distance, and it's not some huge reservoir to move. A pump is overkill.

You could, alternatively, just use a couple empty milk jugs to move one gallon at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I will echo what Chuck said -- this is a pretty simple/ common problem. A basic shop winch will suffice just fine. There are lots of cheap ones on the market (some even come with fancy remotes!)

Check out this one --> [1500 shop winch, for example](https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200672565_200672565?cm_mmc=Google-pla&utm_source=Google_PLA&utm_medium=Winches%20%3E%20AC%20Powered%20Winches&utm_campaign=Ironton&utm_content=54129&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2cC6ub3j3AIVFMpkCh3rJguCEAQYBCABEgJjKPD_BwE)

Comment: Answers should be able to stand on their own and not rely upon another answer as their basis.  While it is okay to say "In addition to what _user_ said, you need to consider X, Y, and Z."  This answer doesn't appear to do that.  All that's novel is the link to a 120V winch that the OP has indicated wouldn't be feasible as there isn't any power supply.  Please consider [edit]ing your answer to provide more detail in a manner that can stand by itself.